# Do creepers make a sound when moving?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

You're in a cavern. It's dark. But your ears work fine, so you know you're safe. All mobs make noise, right? Zombies moan, Spiders squeak, Skeletons' Bones tinkle, Slimes splat, Endermen... make... Ender... Noises? Except... for the dreaded CREEPER, who makes no noise until it's TOO LATE! But... Do creepers make noise when they walk?

No, seriously. Do they? I'm in a cavern and I'm hearing something else taking steps, however I'm not hearing any other noises associated with mobs. Is this a Creeper creeping around somewhere?

Comment: @Mark Trapp While I do understand the title edit, I stand by that mine had more character. :)

Comment: Yessssssssssss they definitly make footssssstepssssssssssss when sssssstalking people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only noises they make is this hissing when they're close to exploding, their hit noise, and explosion noise.

But footstep noises? I do believe they do, but only on certain floor types.

See https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper

Comment: That's a myth, according to my experiments. Creepers make footsteps on **all** block types, in the same way other mobs and players do. (I suspect the source of the myth is the randomness of footstep occurrences for wandering mobs and the quietness of stone footsteps compared to grass footsteps.)

Answer (score 0):

Creepers sometimes make footstep noises, but only on certain blocks.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Could you say which bloks, or produce a source?

Comment: Please refrain from answering a question that has already been answered unless you have some additional information to contribute that wasnt already mentioned in the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they make a noise when they walk around and it sounds like bags being lightly thrown around (the gunpowder sloshing around inside them?) at least in the newer Minecraft.